# liferay returns localhost for CAS instead of real hostname

Tags: liferay, cas, liferay-7

i'm trying to implement CAS in Liferay portal. after setting configurations, when i click on signin button, it redirects me to this url : 
`https://sso.myuni.ac.com:8443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080`.
my real hostname is : www.liferay.myuni.com and the port is 8443.
how can i change settings in order to liferay returns real hostname instead of localhost?
i want to liferay returens `https://sso.myuni.ac.com:8443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fliferay.myuni.com%3A8443`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running with an Apache in front of your tomcat (assuming you're using tomcat)? If you do (and if you use mod_proxy to forward the requests), make sure you also include

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

This will make sure that Tomcat has an idea what the originally requested host name is - otherwise it'll take whatever the Proxyserver sends (when installed on the same server, this is typically localhost).

Read about [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost)

Alternatively, check if you can declare the actual host name in Liferay's configuration, e.g. by searching for `localhost` in [portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html) (you'll override this in portal-ext.properties)

Edit: As you say you only use tomcat, no Apache: Please state what remote host you're actually seeing instead of the expected (and how you obtain it)

With regards to portal.properties: This is a file that is contained within one of Liferay's jars, and is not meant to be modified (that's why it's not easy to find). However, the [HTML version is here](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html), it contains a lot of configuration options. You're overriding by creating a file named `portal-ext.properties` in `${liferay.home}`, containing only those settings that you'd like to change with regards to portal.proerties.

Comment: i only use tomcat, without any proxyserver. i use liferay ver-7. there is not a file named portal.properties. where is it? in other places, users said change portal-ext.properties, there is no such file too.